# Simple example of Ext.view.View on jsfiddle using /echo/json

Tags: extjs

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code on jsfiddle. I am trying to create a reduction to file a bug with Ext-JS. Here's the code I'm using. http://jsfiddle.net/qGBYT/

```
Ext.define('test.Model', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: ['id'],
     idProperty: 'id',
     proxy: {
         // Have also tried 'ajax'
         type: 'rest',
         url: '/echo/json',        
         reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'records'
         }
     }
 }, 

 function(){
     var store = new Ext.data.Store({model:'test.Model'});
     var list = new Ext.view.View({
         itemTpl: '<div>{id}</div>',
         renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 
         width: 300,
         height: 500,
         store: store
     });

     store.load({params: {json: '{"records":[{"id":1}]'}});

 });
```

​
The error message I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

Which is caused by the first line in the code above

Comment: Can you post a link to your fiddle?

Comment: D'oh http://jsfiddle.net/qGBYT/

Comment: Sorry... I tried to move your store creation code from outside the callback and it worked fine - http://jsfiddle.net/qGBYT/11/

Comment: Not sure why it didn't like original one

Comment: That at least gets me through this problem. Post it as an answer, if no one can figure out what the real problem was, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to move your store creation code from outside the callback and it worked fine -

http://jsfiddle.net/qGBYT/11

Not sure why it didn't like original one